# Constant matrix with boost ublas

Tags: c++, boost, constants, boost-ublas

I would like to define a constant 3x3 matrix with boost like this and it will never change during the execution:

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]
```

This matrix will be a member of a class. So, can I define and initialize a constant matrix variable as a class member just like primitive types? When I try to type const for someMatrix variable, I could not assign matrix data in constructor and get this error:

```
error: assignment of read-only location '((Test*)this)->Test::someMatrix.boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>::operator()(0, 0)'
```

Here are codes:

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

namespace bnu = boost::numeric::ublas;

class Test {
private:
    const double a = 1;
    const double b = 2;
    const double c = 3;
    const double d = 4;
    const double e = 5;
    const double f = 6;
    const double g = 7;
    const double h = 8;
    const double i = 9;
    const bnu::matrix<double> someMatrix;

public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

Test.cpp

```
Test::Test(){
    someMatrix(0,0) = a;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
include "Test.h"

int main() {
    Test * t = new Test();

}
```

What I actually want is finding a way to define someMatrix like this:

```
const bnu::matrix<double> someMatrix(3,3) = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper function to do this

```
class Test {
private:
    const bnu::matrix<double> someMatrix;
    static bnu::matrix<double> initSomeMatrix();
public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();
}

Test::Test() : someMatrix(initSomeMatrix()) {
}

bnu::matrix<double> Test::initSomeMatrix() {
    bnu::matrix<double> temp(3, 3);
    temp(0,0) = 1;
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

RVO should make this reasonably efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works, but i needed to declare the size of temp matrix in the first line of initSomeMatrix.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the answer, not very familar with ublas.

Answer (score 6):

Using `<boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp>` you can insert values into an `ublas::matrix` or `ublas::vector` using `<<=` which allows you instatiate your matrix like so:

```
bnu::matrix<double> a(3,3); a <<=  0, 1, 2,
                                   3, 4, 5,
                                   6, 7, 8;
```

To make it constant just copy it:

```
const bnu::matrix<double> b = a;
```

[***HERE***](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4KL9UYknjBt9ZstT) is a working minimal example copied from [here](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/samples/assignment_examples.cpp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works in a cpp,but i could not achieve to define someMatrix as a class member with your suggestion.

Comment: Just [combine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i9xpH7tDqty0K2m5) the two answers ;-)